# Resizing window AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, resize, window

How can I resize the window of the debug player at any time with AS3 code?
I only want to resize the window, not my content or resolution.
I know I can do it by clicking and dragging the border but I would like to be able to adjust the size of the players window by using code. I can not find anything about this anywhere.

Comment: You cannot do it with debug player or projector. You can do it, though, if you are running an AIR application: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#bounds

Comment: yea, I know it can be done by publishing as an air, is there really no way to do it with a projector file?

Comment: No, there are none. Flash Player runtime is browser-compatible and has no control over environment other than https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html#fscommand()